# what data type is a empty DB field?

Tags: string, delphi, variables, types, null

I am trying to count all the non-empty fields in a DB for a school project. Please note im not allowed to use SQL.

Here is the coding

```
var i,k : Integer ;
begin 
  i := 0 ;
  with dmregisteredusers do
  begin
    tblusers.Sort := 'Nommer ASC';
    tblusers.Edit;
    tblusers.First;
    For k:= 1 to tblusers.RecordCount do
    begin
      If (tblusers['Dogs wanted'] = '') OR (tblusers['Dogs wanted'] = ' ') 
        OR (tblusers['Dogswanted'] = 0) 
      then 
        tblusers.Next
      else 
      begin
        inc(i);
        tblusers.Next;
      end;//else
    end;//with
  end;//for
  ShowMessage('There are ' + IntToStr(i) + ' new dogs added to wishlist ,please contact the users regarding this matter and them remove the dogs from their wishlist !');
```

every time I run the code is shows the error that the Db field that is empty is of datatype null.

How can I verify when a DB field is empty?

Comment: [`IsNull`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Data.DB.TField.IsNull)

Comment: You seem to be  missing the space after the third 'Dogs'.  Typo?  Anyway, by using the construct "tblusers['Dogs wanted']" you are accessing the field's contents, if any, as variants (see OLH), and I suspect you are a bit too far out of your depth at the moment to understand what trouble that can cause you with tasks such as your current one. Use tblusers.FieldByName('Dogs wanted') to get at the field.  Its DataType property will tell you what type it is.  Btw, never you a "For" loop to iterate a dataset.  Use a "While not tblusers.Eof do ..." one.  And, what database type are you using?

Comment: Also, Delphi treats the data type of any given column of a dataset as the same for each row in the table.  Null is *not* a value, it is a *state*, meaning the column (field) doesn't have a value for the row in question.  Whoever set your project should have explained this, and the fact that empty <> NULL.  It is an important difference.  If there is a column for middle name and you don't have one, should the field by blank ('') or NULL?  Delphi is actually not especially good at respecting this difference, but you need to be clear about it.

Comment: Interesting way of writing: "wishlist ,please" instead of "wishlist, please". AFAIK there is no space between the word and the punctuation mark, but one space between the punctuation mark and the next word. Just think about what happend on word wrap

Comment: On second/third thoughts, there are too many things to say about your code to deal with in comments.  I will posted a corrected version as an answer in a few minutes.

Comment: Wow guys thanks for comments, second year now of delphi programming so i know i still have a lot to learn...
@sir Rufo once I am done with the project I am going to scan for commonly made punctuation errors, now I am simply trying to finish on time ...

Comment: @martynA i am using a access 2007 Database, registeredusers.mdb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a new version of your code.  It's a bit messy the way I've done it, but I thought it would be easiest to understand if I included comments and explanations in it where the points occur.

The first thing to say is that although it's no bad thing to check for a dataset field being Null for a given row, it's usually better if the database isn't allowed to store Nulls in columns that might ever be queried, by an application or a raw Sql query.  Entire book chapters have been written about what Nulls do or don't mean, in theoretical and practical terms.  In practice, they're usually best thought of as meaning just "information missing".  So we can't answer the question "Does this user want a dog?" in the presence of a Null.  So it's a matter of policy and design choice what do do with a Null, but it's usually far better for the matter to have been decided in the implementation of the database, by imposing a NOT NULL constraint on the column.

When I said in a comment that Delphi isn't especially good at respecting the difference between Nulls and blank fields, what I meant is this:  In the case of a String field, for a row where the field is Null, Delphi returns an empty string, '', when you call Field.AsString.  Some "purists" would say that a TField should generate an exception if asked for its AsXXX property when it contains a Null, because it shouldn't try to "fake" a value when in fact it has none.  What it does instead, i.e. returning an empty string, 0 for a numeric field etc, is a bit of a pragmatic compromise:  It avoids beginners being tripped up by the presence of Nulls, but if you want your code to handle Nulls, you can use TField.IsNull.

If you're stuck with a db containing Nulls - and you will be depressingly often (unless you had a hand in the design of the db) - consider the possibility that they might best be handled in the SQL which gets the data before your Delphi code sees it.

The second thing is that, in the absence of a clear design brief, we don't really know what "wants a dog" means, exactly.  Does it mean the user wants to have a dog singular, plural or Yes/No, for example?  The Yes/No is simplest to deal with, but not all databases support an explicit Boolean column type, so you'll often see a (hopefully single-character) CHAR, VARCHAR (or their Unicode equivalents) column being used instead.  Or an Integer column, if fussy users' requirements are to be entertained.

A third thing is that the Delphi DataType for a field isn't necessarily exactly the same of the db's column type, though there are standard mappings between them,  Regardless, it's usually best to work in your Delphi code with the value representation (e.g. .AsString, .AsInteger, .AsFloat, to name but a few) which best matches the db column type.

Admittedly, not all database implementations are as fussy, sorry, I mean careful, as Delphi is in dealing with the datatypes of columns, but most are.  A notable exception is Sqlite, where although you can define your columns types in the table's DDL, the Sqlite engine treats these more like recommendations than rules and you can store pretty much anything in them.

As I said in a comment earlier, Null is a column/field *state*, rather than a value.  So asking "What data type is an empty DB field?" is a variety of "category error".  The data type of a column is "exactly what it says on the tin", i.e. what it's defined to be in the table's DDL.  What you were really asking, of course, is "How do I determine whether the field is empty", and that is as much a matter of design choice and db implementation as it is of Delphi coding.

Anyway, enough of generalities ...

```
procedure CountDogsWanted;
var
  // i,k : Integer ; <- names like i and k are usually as used for loop variables
  DogsWanted : Integer;
  Wanted : Boolean;
  S : String;  // contrast this naming style with what I said about the likes of i, j, k
    // I've done this because we might want to do several tests & operations on its value
    // and they will be easier to read with a shorter variable name.  Not such a good idea
    // when there are several such variables.
  AField : TField; 
const
  scDogsWanted = 'Dogs wanted';  // this is to avoid making mistakes with typos
begin

  {i := 0 ;}
  DogsWanted := 0;

  //  The point of the following line is to retrieve the field we're working with
  //  only once, rather than doing a FieldByName (which involves a serial iteration
  //  through the dataset's Fields collection) for each row in the dataset.
  //  The AField variable will remain valid for the duration of this procedure
  //  or until the dataset is closed if its Fields aren't defined as persistent ones.
  //  Persistent fields remain valid for the lifetime of their owners (usually a 
  // datamodule or form).  OTOH, "dynamic" fields are owned by the dataset and created
  // and destroyed when the dataset is opened and closed.  

  AField := dmregisteredusers.tblusers.FieldByName(scDogsWanted);

  {with dmregisteredusers do  <- Don't use "with", it only ever causes problems}
  {begin}

    {tblusers.Sort := 'Nommer ASC'; <- pointless, it makes no difference when you count what order the things are in}

    {tblusers.Edit; <- No! This puts the table into Edit state, but there's not point because you're not changing anything, and in any case, it will drop out of Edit state when you do a .Next}

    dmregisteredusers.tblusers.First;
    while not dmregisteredusers.tblusers.Eof do
    {For k:= 1 to tblusers.RecordCount do <- Never, ever, iterate a dataset with a For loop.
     The RecordCount is best avoided, too, because not all types of dataset return a meaningful
     RecordCount }

    begin
      //  You need to decide what to do about users whose 'Dogs wanted' field is Null
      //  If is is Null maybe we should ask for the record to be changed to indicate
      // explicitly whether a dog is wanted or not

      if AField.IsNull then begin
        // to be filled in by you
      end;
      //  You haven't told us what DataType the 'Dogs wanted' field is
      //  There are several possibilities.  For simplicity, let's assume that the DataType of the field is ftString
      //  Let's also make a design decision that *only* if the field only contains a 'Y' in upper or lower
      //  case, then that means a dog is wanted.
      //  First copy the field's string value into a local variable so we don't have to keep getting it for the
      //  following operation;
      S := dmregisteredusers.tblUsers.FieldByName(scDogsWanted).AsString;
      S := Trim(S);  { Trim() is a statndard function which removes leading and trailing whitespace }
      Wanted := CompareText(S, 'Y') = 0; { CompareText does a case-insensitive comparison and returns zero if equal}
      If
        { (tblusers['Dogs wanted'] = '') OR (tblusers['Dogs wanted'] = ' ')
          OR (tblusers['Dogswanted'] = 0)}
        Wanted
      then
        {tblusers.Next <- this is in the wrong place, you want to do a .Next regardless of the outcome of the "if"}
      else
      begin
        inc(DogsWanted);
        {tblusers.Next;}
      end;//else
      dmregisteredusers.tblusers.Next;
    {end;//with}
  end;//for
  ShowMessage('There are ' + IntToStr(DogsWanted) + ' new dogs added to wishlist ,please contact the users regarding this matter and them remove the dogs from their wishlist !')
end;
```

Comment: Though using constant is better than repeating yourself, a variable holding a reference to the field would be nicer.

Comment: @TLama: I agree entirely, but just wondered whether doing that would maybe obscure the point that referring consistently to the field's name is a good and rather necessary first step, especially with fieldnames with embedded whitespace (which I personally loath).  I will do it on my next pass.

Answer (score 0):

guys as much as i appreciate the effort you put into the answers i cannot use them as my instructor would know its not my own work...
@MartynA your coding had the answer to my question
 here is the new coding 
i know its sloppy and there are many other ways it could work but im really pressed for time so cant take time to learn the code...here is what i will use

```
For k:= 1 to tblusers.RecordCount do
begin
If dmregisteredusers.tblusers.FieldByName('Dogs wanted').IsNull then tblusers.Next
else
    begin
   inc(i) ;
   tblusers.Next;
   end//then begin
```

I used the sorting of the db form.onshow so when the DBGrid displays it would be in correct order ...

Comment: Sure, we all know what working under time pressure, no probs, and anyway SO as as much for future readers as the immediate needs of the questioner.  But if I were you, I'd nail a note to my instructor's forehead to explain Nulls and the problems they cause, and to say that in your code, you're effectively assuming that Null means "No dog, thanks", which may not reflect how the data has actually been entered.

Comment: Yes exactly..the user asks for a dog,admin has to be notified how many people want one,if not null it means they want a dog...sounds so easy until you have to convert it into code...also im using code to input data into the DB so only certain values could be present in the field...